# Store Time from datetime and use it later. SQLite3

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to save a known time in SQLite and use it at a later date
I know we can do;

```
WHEN = time(21, 0, 0)

async def waiting():
  now = datetime.now()
  if now.time() > WHEN:
  #irrelevant code
```

At this point i would like to use the same concept, but save "21, 0, 0" and use that later.
Here's what I've been working on.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def testing():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        now = datetime.now()
        db = sqlite3.connect('aDatabase.db')
        db.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT time FROM guildData WHERE guild_id = {guild.id}")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        db.close()
       # print (time(results[0]))
        if now.time() == results[0]:
       #     print("pass")
```

The issue I run into all the time is the error:

> print (time(results[0]))
> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I cant seem to convert the str to int, or vice versa.

The over all goal here is to be able to store 21, 0, 0 (or whatever time). Every hour check the whole list with a loop and check to see if the hour is correct, then post for that guild.

I hope I've explained this well, and i really appreciate any help. A good possibility im looking at this all wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the result of `print(repr(results[0]))`?  If you want it to be the string `21, 0, 0`, you need `datetime.strptime` to parse that.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I can't seem to get that to work too :/.

Comment: Get what to work? the `print` I asked for or `strptime`?  Edit your question with a [mcve] and be specific.  Show the full traceback of the error.

Comment: @MarkTolonen repr prints out '21, 0, 0'. Thanks, ill do this.